# The difference between selectedindexchanged and textchanged

Tags: asp.net

Can someone please explain to me the difference between `SelectedIndexChanged` and `TextChanged` in a `RadioButtonList`?

Answer (score 1):

In practical terms, nothing, since I'm not certain how you would raise one event without the other.

However, SelectedIndexChanged is the event that should be used to determine when the index of the control has been changed by the user.  The TextChanged event is provided for internal purposes, so that other container controls (which may contain text boxes, radio buttons, etc.) can test for a single event to determine that something was modified.